# Use prettier to change indent size of already existing code

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I generated project with nuxt-create CLI. It asked me if I want eslint and prettier and I said yes. Then in `.editorconfig` I changed `index_size` to 4 because I want my tab to be 4 spaces.

Now when I run `lint` command it obviously display tones of errors that spacing is incorrect as expected.

Can I use prettier or eslint to have a npm script for example `npm run fix:tabs` which would fix for me spaces in entire project (which means to convert current 2 spaces into 4 everywhere*)?

*For now I just need to convert 2 into 4; 6 into 12; 4 into 8 etc.. Side question is if I can somehow create a script which would know if it needs to convert. For example if in one file spaces would be correct and in another one not then the script would convert spaces only in incorrect one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "prettier --write" on the files to make them confirm to the prettier settings.

In your package json you'd add the following command:

```
"fix:tabs": "prettier --write **/*.js"
```

or even:

```
"fix:tabs": "prettier --write **/*.{js,ts,html}"
```